# Qt5 C++ UTF-8 convertion to Windows-1250 of Romanian ș and ț characters

Tags: c++11, utf-8, qt5, cp1250

My application is developed in C++'11 and uses Qt5. In this application, I need to store a UTF-8 text as Windows-1250 coded file.
I tried two following ways and both work expect for Romanian 'ș' and 'ț' characters :(

  1.

```
    auto data = QStringList() << ... <some texts here>;
    QTextStream outStream(&destFile);
    outStream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1250"));
    foreach (auto qstr, data)
    {
        outStream << qstr << EOL_CODE;
    }
```

  2.

```
    auto data = QStringList() << ... <some texts here>;
    auto *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1250");
    foreach (auto qstr, data)
    {
        const QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(qstr);
        destFile.write(encodedString);
    }
```

In case of 'ț' character (alias 0xC89B), instead of expected 0xFE value, the character is coded and stored as 0x3F, that it is unexpected.

So I am looking for any help or experience / examples regarding text recoding.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you check that `codecForName` is not returning 0? By the way, you can also [pass a string to `setCodec` directly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-1).

Comment: Hi @Thomas. No, codecForName does not return nullptr and other Romanian characters are correctly converted... Only  'ș' and 'ț' exhibit this strange behavior. I tried to pass a string to setCodec method and the behavior is the same

Comment: 0xFE in Windows-1250 is "t with cedilla", U+0163. You have U+021B, "t with comma below". It's not representable in codepage 1250, so the conversion produces the question mark, 0x3F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse `ț` with `ţ`. The former is what is in your post, the latter is what's actually supported by [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250).

The character ț from your post is T-comma, U+021B, [LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH COMMA BELOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-comma), however:

> This letter was not part of the early Unicode versions, which is why Ţ (T-cedilla, available from version 1.1.0, June 1993) is often used in digital texts in Romanian.

The character referred to is ţ, U+0163, [LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH CEDILLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A2) (emphasis mine):

> In early versions of Unicode, the Romanian letter Ț (T-comma) was considered a glyph variant of Ţ, and therefore was not present in the Unicode Standard. **It is also not present in the Windows-1250 (Central Europe) code page.**

The story of `ş` and `ș`, being [S-cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9E) and [S-comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-comma) is analogous.

If you must encode to this archaic Windows 1250 code page, I'd suggest replacing the comma variants by the cedilla variants (both lowercase and uppercase) before encoding. I think Romanians will understand :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check the appropriate letters to use with people who translates the data.